# Cast/Convert const vector<uint8_t> to const vector<char> in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

What would be the most performant way to convert/cast `const vector<uint8_t>` to `const vector<char>` in c++?

Comment: While definitely not standard compliant, if the `uint8_t` is `typedef`ed to `unsigned char` (as it usually is) you can probably get away with a plain old C-style cast

Comment: definitely not standard compliant ;-)

Comment: note that you can alias the contents if that would solve the problem

Comment: @M.M can you please provide an example of aliasing of the vector<uint8_t> to const vector<char> ?

Comment: @Tito you can alias the contents, not the vector. E.g. `const char *p = (const char *)&v[0];`

Answer (score 1):

This should work (untested code):

```
std::vector<uint8_t> v1 = // something;
const char *p = (const char *) v1.data();
std::vector<char> v2(p, p + v1.size());
```

Now you have two vectors; one of `uint8_t`s and one of `chars`

One memory allocation, one call to `memcpy`.

[Later: @Tito pointed out that vector doesn't have a (pointer, size) constructor (like `string`/`span`/`string_view`) Rewrote the example code to use the (iterator, iterator) constructor instead]

Comment: Marschall  there is no  matching constructor for such initialization. Are you sure this is correct?